# GDownloadUrl with & sign as part of the input characters

Tags: php

I have a page sending data to .php page to insert it into db. The code is as below.

```
var stringInput = "gName="+gName+"&gDescription="+gDescription+"&gPreference="+gPreference;
GDownloadUrl("insertPage.php", checkSaveGeoFenceData,stringInput,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Only problem we are facing now is that for instance the gName itself have & sign as part of the information and only the part before & gets into the db. Any resolution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `urlencode()` as like

```
$gName = urlencode($gName);
```

To `decode it afterward` in your php

```
$gName = urldecode($gName);
```

EDIT

If this is in javascript, then

```
var stringInput = "gName="+gName+"&gDescription="+gDescription+"&gPreference="+gPreference;

stringInput = encodeURIComponent(stringInput);
```

Comment: so I do this right var stringInput = "gName="+urlencode(gName)+"&gDescription="+urlencode(gDescription)+"&gPreference="+urlencode(gPreference); then in the php page I do this for e.g. $gName=urldecode($_POST['gName']);

Comment: yes in php so what is your suggestion then but the calling is down via ajax

Comment: I got it to urlencode in the javascript how about during the capture process in php do I need to urldecode the values individually?

Comment: yes. use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php and then urldecode each value

Comment: @gdb currently in the php I am capturing via $_POST method which is working so what changes must I add in then ? Just add the urldecode is it?

Comment: what you get if var_dump($_POST) ? $_POST is superglobal of php and it's already urldecoded

Comment: I normally do this $_POST['gName'] and I get all the values accordingly sent from the javascript. So what changes to make in php the $_POST['gName'];

Comment: no it does not so I leave it as it is just do the changes on the javascript I guess am I right? Thank you.